# adding a list field in mongo (python)

Tags: python, pymongo

I have an id which some tags are associated with and I want to fill a collection with those tags. How do I do this?

Suppose I have the following:

```
key: 12345, tags = ["foo","bar","foobar"]
```

So I am hoping to get a document in a collection named "Tags" like this:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fbaa6076a56b2700d000000"), 
  "key" : 12345, 
  "tags" : ["foo","bar","foobar"] 
}
```

How do I do this in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mongo_conn.Tags.insert({
    "key": 12345,
    "tags": ["foo","bar","foobar"]
})
```